# SO_RCVTIMEO wakes up too early

Tags: linux, sockets, timeout, posix, darwin

The [Linux manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) for SO_RCVTIMEO says:

> Specify the receiving or sending timeouts until reporting an error... If an input or output function blocks for this period of time... [and] no data has been transferred and the timeout has been reached, then -1 is returned with errno set to EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK, or EINPROGRESS (for connect(2))

This sounds to me like the I/O should wait *at least* the SO_RCVTIMEO before returning execution to the caller.  Meanwhile, [at the Open Group](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setsockopt.html), they document the opposite:

> Sets the timeout value that specifies the *maximum* amount of time an input function waits until it completes.

So which is it, a minimum blocking time or a maximum blocking time?  The answer appears to be: yes.  Here is what happens when I ask for a .500s timeout on a Linux system:

```
time: 0.497054 result: 0
time: 0.495352 result: 0
time: 0.504948 result: 0
time: 0.495119 result: 0
time: 0.507884 result: 0
time: 0.491892 result: 0
time: 0.500764 result: 0
```

We see that the time is wrong, typically by as much as 7ms or so, which is a long time to be wrong by. And error happens in both directions.  Meanwhile on Darwin:

```
time: 0.500426 result: -1
time: 0.501144 result: -1
time: 0.500507 result: -1
time: 0.501119 result: -1
time: 0.501016 result: -1
time: 0.500540 result: -1
time: 0.500127 result: -1
time: 0.500815 result: -1
time: 0.500341 result: -1
time: 0.500871 result: -1
time: 0.500835 result: -1
time: 0.501138 result: -1
time: 0.501087 result: -1
time: 0.501153 result: -1
time: 0.501149 result: -1
```

Error is much lower (~1ms), but still exists, and they clearly interpret 500ms as a minimum time, not maximum.

Now some questions:

- Is SO_RCVTIMEO supposed to be a minimum or a maximum duration for blocking the caller?
- If it's a maximum duration, what is the minimum?  Surely an implementation is not free to choose a nonblocking read when asked for a 500ms timeout?
- If it's a minimum duration, is Darwin wrong?
- If I want to guarantee I tried to read for *at least* 500ms, am I supposed to keep trying in a loop until 500ms elapses?  What is the "right way" to implement "at least X ms" behavior?
- Why is there so much variation from call to call on Linux?  What is the source of the error?
- Is there a better API I should be using to read from sockets instead?

Code I used to measure this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#ifdef __MACH__
#include <mach/clock.h>
#include <mach/mach.h>
#endif
void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

struct timespec os_time() {
    struct timespec ts;
    #ifdef __MACH__ // OS X does not have clock_gettime, use clock_get_time
    clock_serv_t cclock;
    mach_timespec_t mts;
    host_get_clock_service(mach_host_self(), CALENDAR_CLOCK, &cclock);
    clock_get_time(cclock, &mts);
    mach_port_deallocate(mach_task_self(), cclock);
    ts.tv_sec = mts.tv_sec;
    ts.tv_nsec = mts.tv_nsec;

    #else
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
    #endif
    return ts;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
     socklen_t clilen;
     char buffer[256];
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
     int n;
     if (argc < 2) {
         fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
         exit(1);
     }
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0)
        error("ERROR opening socket");
     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     portno = atoi(argv[1]);
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
              sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
              error("ERROR on binding");
     listen(sockfd,5);
     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
     newsockfd = accept(sockfd,
                 (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr,
                 &clilen);
     if (newsockfd < 0)
          error("ERROR on accept");
     for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
         struct timeval tv;

         tv.tv_sec = 0;
         tv.tv_usec = 500000;
         char buf[1];
         if (setsockopt(newsockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&tv,sizeof(struct timeval)) != 0){
             error("setsockopt error");
         }
         struct timespec start = os_time();
         int result = recv(newsockfd,buf,1,0);
         struct timespec end = os_time();

         double end_time = (double)end.tv_sec + ((double)end.tv_nsec)/1.0E9;
         double start_time = (double)start.tv_sec + ((double)start.tv_nsec)/1.0E9;
         printf("time: %f result: %d\n",end_time-start_time, result);
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Reproduction:

```
clang test.c && ./a.out 5551 &
telnet localhost 5551
time: 0.497839 result: 0
time: 0.501052 result: 0
time: 0.498565 result: 0
time: 0.500741 result: 0
time: 0.500108 result: 0
time: 0.500244 result: 0
time: 0.499040 result: 0
time: 0.500212 result: 0
time: 0.500137 result: 0
time: 0.499920 result: 0
time: 0.500758 result: 0
time: 0.498068 result: 0
```

Answer (score 3):

> This sounds to me like the I/O should wait at least the SO_RCVTIMEO before returning execution to the caller.

No. It should wait *at most* the timeout. If data is already there, or arrives before the timeout, the method returns at that point, without waiting for the timeout to expire.

> Meanwhile, at the Open Group, they document the opposite:
>
> > Sets the timeout value that specifies the maximum amount of time an input function waits until it completes.
>
> So which is it, a minimum blocking time or a maximum blocking time?

A maximum blocking time.

> they clearly interpret 500ms as a minimum time, not maximum.

Here you're asking, and testing, two different questions: the resolution of the timer and the speed with which the operating system reschedules the thread after the timeout. Neither is specified.

> Is SO_RCVTIMEO supposed to be a minimum or a maximum duration for blocking the caller?

Maximum, within its (i.e. the operating system's) resolution, and subject to further scheduling delays.

> If it's a maximum duration, what is the minimum?

Zero.

> Surely an implementation is not free to choose a nonblocking read when asked for a 500ms timeout?

Of course it is. If data is already present in the socket receive buffer, `recv()` transfers that data and returns immediately. Why should it wait?

> If it's a minimum duration, is Darwin wrong?

No, it just has different resolution and rescheduling delay.

> If I want to guarantee I tried to read for at least 500ms, am I supposed to keep trying in a loop until 500ms elapses? What is the "right way" to implement "at least X ms" behavior?

You would have to do that with your own timer but I cannot see the point. If data is already there, or arrives earlier, why on earth would you want to delay?

> Why is there so much variation from call to call on Linux? What is the source of the error?

Timer jitter; rescheduling jitter. It isn't a real-time operating system

> Is there a better API I should be using to read from sockets instead?

Define 'better'. Your expectations seem rather strange. This API has been good enough for everybody else for over 30 years.

Comment: "If data is already there, or arrives before the timeout, the method returns at that point, without waiting for the timeout to expire."


I understand that.  The situation I'm asking about is when data does NOT arrive.  In that case, Linux gives up 490ms into a 500ms timeout.  Is that sensible?  Or what is to prevent Linux from instead giving up at 0ms into a 500ms timeout?


Or to ask another way: if I know that some data will be readable exactly 500ms from now, what value of SO_RCVTIMEO will guarantee read will succeed?

Comment: What is to prevent it is the specification, but you need to understand that timers have granularity. For example on Windows it is 16ms. You can't get more granularity than is in there.

Comment: Where is the specification?  Where can I find out how long or short a timeout might be on Linux?

Comment: I'm referring to the specification of SO_RCVTIMEO. I have no idea what the timer granularity is on Linux or where you would find out. *man 7 time* might be a starting point.

Comment: How does "the specification of SO_RCVTIMEO" (what specification, the manpage?) prevent the OS from giving up after trying for 0ms?

Comment: Because it specifies the read timeout in milliseconds and the clear expectation is that the value supplied is respected, within reasonable limits. The implementation you mention would be entirely unreasonable and indeed useless. This is not a serious question.

Comment: It's a completely serious question.  You're suggesting that the implementation need not wait for the timeout.  So: what must it wait for?  Must it wait for anything?

Comment: I haven't suggested anything of the sort. I stated that the implementation cannot implement the timeout exactly due to (a) timer jitter (b) rescheduling jitter and (c) not being a real-time operating system. An implementation that doesn't block at all when there is no data clearly doesn't comply. An implementation that is within 1% or so as your data shows is surely adequate? I will add that 500mS is a very short read timeout. Usually they are measured in tens of seconds.

Comment: It may be adequate to be +/- 2%, but I don't know if the implementation guarantees that, or if it's just what happens on my system.

Comment: In addition, it seems if an error occurs (disconnect etc.), `recv` may return much sooner than the SO_RCVTIMEO with EAGAIN or other `errno`